# How to put transparent JPanel over an opaque JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, awt

I have added webcam to my software using `com.github.sarxos.webcam`. It has a `JPanel` named `WebcamPanel` and has predefined webcam sizes while I need my custom size of pictures. I managed to crop the images taken from webcam at `640 x 480`. I want to put a red rectangle over the `WebcamPanel` to show that this part of the image will be saved.

```
public class CardPanel {
    Dimension panelDim = new Dimension(640, 480);

    public Cardpanel(){
        //....Button Defined earlier

        btnTakePhoto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                webcameFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private void webcamFrame(){

        imageFrame = new JFrame("Photo Capture");
        // Did some calculations to put window at center
        imageFrame.setBounds(screenSize.width / 2 - frameWidth / 2, screenSize.height / 2 - frameHeight / 2, frameWidth,
            frameHeight);
        imageFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        imageFrame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel webcamWindow = new JPanel();

        RedHighlighter redHighlighter = new RedHighlighter();

        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());

        webcamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        webcamPanel.setFillArea(true);
        webcamPanel.setMirrored(false);
        webcamPanel.setPreferredSize(panelDim);

        webcamWindow.add(webcamPanel);
        webcamWindow.add(redHighlighter);

        hBox.add(webcamWindow);
   }

   // Sub Class just for drawing the rectangle
   public class RedHighlighter extends JPanel{

        public RedHighlighter() {
            // If you delete the following line, nothing will appear
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

I used `JLayeredPanes` but no matter what you do it will cover whole size and will show only one item at a time.

Overriding `paint` method helped me draw the rectangle but it's on side and not on top.

[image]
As you can see the rectangle has pushed `WebcamPanel` towards left. I want `webcamPanel` to remain in it's position while the rectangle on top of it at center. Please suggest an efficient approach to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Compoents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for one way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The one JPanel is being pushed over due to the layout managers that you are using. If you want one JPanel to overly another, you'll want to consider using a JLayeredPane, with the video images in the lower level, perhaps the `JLayeredPane.DEFAULT` layer, and the drawing JPanel above it.

Other options and issues:

- You could potentially draw in the same JPanel that the image is being displayed in by displaying the image in a paintComponent method as well as the drawing (in lines of code *after* the image is displayed.
- Look into use of a JLayer as a way of adding a drawing "decoration" over your image.
- Always override paintComponent, **not** paint
- Always call the super's painting method within your override.

Comment: `WebcamPanel` is from **github** in binary and I'm afraid I can't edit it. I tried `JLayeredPane` with a preferred size but that would resize to cover whole area even after `setOpaque(false)` I couldn't see webcam.

Comment: @MirwiseKhan: without your current pertinent code, it's hard to guess what problems you might be having. Please edit your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFulllOfEels Code Updated

Comment: @MirwiseKhan: ?? you're still overriding `paint`, not `paintComponent`, and are still not calling the super's painting method (paintComponent if overriding that method). This is important, otherwise I wouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @MirwiseKhan: ?? and you don't show any JLayeredPane code. How are we to figure out what could be wrong without this?

Comment: @MirwiseKhan You don't need to change the source code, simply create a custom class by extending from `WebcamPanel` and overriding its `paintComponent` method

Comment: Yep, just as @MadProgrammer says. But also (and again) if you do this, be absolutely sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method in your own override.

Answer (score 0):

It worked!

```
public class MyWebcamPanel extends WebcamPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2808353446021354508L;

    public MyWebcamPanel(Webcam webcam) {
        super(webcam);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = 180;
        int y = 87;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 640-2*x, 480-2*y);

    }

}
```